# How to exclude assembly from package in sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

I have a build.scala file that has a section that looks something like the clip below.
I use sbt-assembly to build a jar file of all dependent libs for deployment.

This builds fine.  My problem is that I run 'assembly' and that builds ~16MB core-deps file, then I run 'package' trying to build the core.jar file.  It builds core.jar--but then it overwrites my core-deps.jar file with an empty file (because core-deps has no code of its own).

How can I build both core.jar and core-deps.jar and not have 'package' blow away core-deps.jar?

```
lazy val deps = Project("core-deps", file("."), 
    settings = basicSettings ++ 
                sbtassembly.Plugin.assemblySettings ++ 
                Seq(assemblyOption in assembly ~= { _.copy(includeScala = false) }) ++
                addArtifact(Artifact("core-deps", "core-deps"), sbtassembly.Plugin.AssemblyKeys.assembly) ++    
                Seq(
                    libraryDependencies ++=
                        // Master list of all used libraries so it gets added to the deps.jar file when you run assembly
                        compile(commons_exec, commons_codec, commons_lang, casbah, googleCLHM, joda_time, scalajack, spray_routing, spray_can, spray_client, spray_caching, akka_actor, akka_cluster, akka_slf4j, prettytime, mongo_java, casbah_gridfs, typesafe_config, logback),
                    jarName in assembly <<= (scalaVersion, version) map { (scalaVersion, version) => "core-deps_" + scalaVersion.dropRight(2) + "-" + version + ".jar" } 
                )) aggregate(core)

lazy val core = project 
    .settings(basicSettings: _*)
    .settings(buildSettings: _*)
    .settings(libraryDependencies ++=
        compile(commons_exec, prettytime, commons_codec, casbah, googleCLHM, scalajack, casbah_gridfs, typesafe_config, spray_routing, spray_client, spray_can, spray_caching, akka_actor, akka_slf4j, akka_cluster, logback) ++
        test(scalatest, parboiled, spray_client)
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `assemblyPackageDependency` task that comes with sbt-assembly? See [Excluding Scala library, your project, or deps JARs](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#excluding-scala-library-your-project-or-deps-jars).

If for some reason you really want to disable `package` task in core-deps project, you could try rewiring the `packageBin`:

```
packageBin := (outputPath in assembly).value
```

That will do nothing but return the file name.